# How can I filter query results of a Vora table based on an aggregate value?

Tags: vora

I have a defined a Vora View which has a single Relational Table data source. I have included two columns in my result set, one of which I have assigned an aggregate function. The data preview of this works as expected.

Logically, I want to add a 'where' clause to filter the data only when the aggregate value satisfies a condition. In order to do this with an aggregate value, it is my understanding that I need to define a 'HAVING' clause. So, this is what I did, but it results in the following exception:

> org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure:
>   Task 0 in stage 9147.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost task
>   0.0 in stage 9147.0 (TID 246678, localhost): sap.hanavora.jdbc.VoraException: HL(9): Runtime error.
>   (sql_error:1:193-1:203: error: Unresolved reference SELECT
>   "__subquery1"."CHARGE_DEPARTMENT", AVG("__subquery1"."COST") AS
>   "AVG_COST" FROM (SELECT "HC_SERVICE"."CHARGE_DEPARTMENT",
>   "HC_SERVICE"."COST" FROM "HC_SERVICE") AS "__subquery1" WHERE
>   ("AVG_COST" > 500.0) GROUP BY "__subquery1"."CHARGE_DEPARTMENT" LIMIT
>   1000 ^^^^^^^^^^ ) at
>   sap.hanavora.jdbc.driver.HLMessage.buildException(HLMessage.java:97)
>   at
>   ...

I have tried the same using the SQL Editor and I get the same exception result, here is the query:

```
select CHARGE_DEPARTMENT, avg(COST) as AVERAGE_COST
from HC_SERVICE
group by CHARGE_DEPARTMENT
having AVERAGE_COST > 500.00;
```

I've also tried moving the initial query into a subselect and then trying to apply the having clause to that result set but I end up getting the same error. But I don't think that is necessary because it appears (based on the exception) that the Vora engine is already building a subquery in this case.

Comment: Update: I am running Vora 1.4 and this issue, in my case, is specific to the new Vora Relational Engine. I can confirm that the Vora In-Memory Engine works as expected and may be used as an alternate means to create Views or Chart Filters which leverage aggregate columns.

Comment: I'm now running 1.4.20 and this is only partially fixed. I can apply a simple HAVING clause now, but if I try to add an 'AND' condition on the same aggregate field, I get an error. For example, this SQL causes an error:

`SELECT CHARGE_DEPARTMENT , (AVG(COST)) AS AVERAGE_COST  
FROM  SERVICE 
GROUP BY CHARGE_DEPARTMENT 
HAVING AVERAGE_COST > 200 AND AVERAGE_COST < 450
ORDER BY CHARGE_DEPARTMENT;`

This same SQL still works on the Vora In-Memory Engine, but not with the Relational Engine. Can you confirm if this is fixed in another patch or in 2.0?

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to do this in the Vora Tools modeller?

If you're just using SQL then this should give you the result you want:

```
select CHARGE_DEPARTMENT, AVERAGE_COST from (
    select CHARGE_DEPARTMENT, avg(COST) as AVERAGE_COST
    from HC_SERVICE
    group by CHARGE_DEPARTMENT
    ) as subQuery
where subQuery.AVERAGE_COST > 500.00;
```

Comment: Yes, I am trying to build a Vora View based on this query and I did try using a SubSelect in the Modeler too. Thank you for the direct SQL suggestion. However, I get the same exception when trying that SQL.

Answer (score 0):

The error "... Unresolved reference..." with HAVING is due to a bug in Vora. It is planned to be fixed in the next Vora 1.4 patch. There is no workaround for this issue.

Update 7/6/2017: This issue is fixed in Vora 1.4 patch 2 (available since 7/3/2017)